# How we can calculate starting and ending indices of specific string in a cell array in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, duplicates, unique, cell

Suppose that we have this cell array:

```
strings = {'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'b'; 'b'; 'b'; 'b'; 'm'; 'm'; 'm'; 'm'};
```

I want something like this as the output:

```
a  1    6
b  7    10
m  11   14
```

The numbers are showing the start and ending indices of every unique string. However, this is just an example. My cell array has more than 100 unique strings. What would be an efficient way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: What would your output be if `strings = {'a','b','a','b'};`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outputs of [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) should give you what you're looking for right out of the box:

```
strings = {'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'b'; 'b'; 'b'; 'b'; 'm'; 'm'; 'm'; 'm'};
[uniquestrings, start, bin] = unique(strings);
```

Where:

```
uniquestrings = 

    'a'    'b'    'm'


start =

     1     7    11


bin =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     2     2     2     2     3     3     3     3
```

While this works well for the data provided, I'd be curious to see a more 'real' representative data set to perhaps make the function more generic.

Answer (score 3):

Start with `unique` to map your data to indices:

```
[~,~,ix]=unique(strings);
d=[];
%calculate end indices
d(:,2)=[find(diff(ix));numel(ix)]
%calculate start indices
d(:,1)=[1;d(1:end-1,2)+1]
%corresponding chars:
e=strings(d(:,1))
```

output is:

```
d =

     1     6
     7    10
    11    14


e = 

    'a'
    'b'
    'm'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your strings are populated in a way where you have consecutive runs of strings and that run is **the only time** you'll see a particular unique string, you can combine this with [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).  First, use `unique` to get a list of all unique strings, then assign each string to have a unique ID from 1 up to as many unique strings that you have.  The thing with `unique` is that the IDs are assigned once you **sort** the strings.  You don't want to do this because you want to use the positions of the strings as is to determine the start and end positions of their runs.  As such, you'll need to use the `'stable'` flag.  You'll need the first output which gives you the unique strings in the array (for later) and the third output to get this new ID assignment:

```
strings = {'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'b'; 'b'; 'b'; 'b'; 'm'; 'm'; 'm'; 'm'};
[s,~,id] = unique(strings, 'stable');
```

Now that you have this, use `accumarray` so that you can take each ID and group them together.  In this case, you'll want to use the position numbers associated with each unique string and you'll want to bin all of the position numbers that belong to the same ID of a character together.  Once you do this, we can output a cell array of elements where each element is a two element vector that gives you the smallest and largest position of each run.

```
out = accumarray(id, (1:numel(strings)).', [], @(x) {[min(x), max(x)]});
```

You can then display this in a nice table:

```
T = table(s, vertcat(out{:}), 'VariableNames', {'Letter', 'BeginEnd'});
```

We get:

```
T = 

    Letter    BeginEnd
    ______    ________

    'a'        1     6
    'b'        7    10
    'm'       11    14
```

---

However, if you want to get the first and last elements in a matrix, simply do:

```
ind = vertcat(out{:});
```

The first column gives you the starting locations of each character and the second column gives you the ending locations of each character.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using `unique`:

```
strings = {'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'a'; 'b'; 'b'; 'b'; 'b'; 'm'; 'm'; 'm'; 'm'};
[u, l] = unique(strings, 'last');
[~, f] = unique(strings, 'first');
```

This gives

```
u = 
    'a'
    'b'
    'm'
f =
     1
     7
    11
l =
     6
    10
    14
```

Or you can concatenate the results in a cell array

```
result = [u num2cell([f l])]
```

to produce

```
result = 
    'a'    [ 1]    [ 6]
    'b'    [ 7]    [10]
    'm'    [11]    [14]
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh! First and last flags. Very clever!

Comment: @rayryeng Recently I've been reviewing all possible input flags for many functions (for MATL). Something good had to come from that :-)